# program on Javascript doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

I've a problem with result of this program: when I checked "Protector", "Headset", "Case" and "Games" as a result I should receive "Kindle", "Nokia" and "Wii". However, I receive only one value - "Kindle" (this is in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer). In addition, I receive all the values (duplicated also) this is in Opera.
Can you help me to resolve these problems.
Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function product(){ 
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('checkboxes');
    var i=0;
    var j=0;
    var tech = [
    ["Kindle","Protector"],
    ["Iphone","Headset"],
    ["Iphone","US Charger"],
    ["Iphone","USB cable"],
    ["Iphone","Case"],
    ["Nokia","Protector"],
    ["Nokia","Headset"],
    ["Nokia","Case"],
    ["Wii","Games"]
    ];

    for (i=0 ; i < tech.length; i++){
        for(j=0 ; j< checkboxes.length; j++){
            if ((tech[i][1] == checkboxes[j].value)&&(checkboxes[j].checked)){
            document.write(tech[i][0]);
            document.write("<br>");
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form name="Accessories">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="Protector"> Protector <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="Headset"> Headset <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="US Charger"> US Charger <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="USB cable"> USB cable <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="Case"> Case <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="Games"> Games </br>
<input type="button" name="Check" onClick="product()" value="Search a product">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment you use document.write() your form elements exist no more so your checkboxes array will not be present. That is the reason why you are getting just 'kindle'. Try to use console.log(tech[i][0]) instead and run it in chrome. You should get: Kindle, Iphone, Iphone, Nokia, Nokia, Nokia, Wii.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `document.write()` after the page has rendered will obliterate the page completely. In some browsers, that means that the JavaScript code itself will stop working.

What you can try instead is this:

1. Add a `<div>` to the end of your page (inside the `<body>` of course) and give it an "id" value of "settings".
2. Change your code to set its contents:

   ```
   var content = "";
   for (i=0 ; i < tech.length; i++){
       for(j=0 ; j< checkboxes.length; j++){
           if ((tech[i][1] == checkboxes[j].value)&&(checkboxes[j].checked)){
             content += tech[i][0] + '<br>';
           }
       }
   }
   document.getElementById("settings").innerHTML = content;
   ```

Comment: This is working, but the second problem is staying. When I check something the result should return unique values that all parameters are checked. For example: when I checked "Protector" the result should be only "Kindle", not "Kindle" and "Nokia" because for "Nokia" other parameters are not checked. Thanks for helping me

Comment: @user2432205 nothing in your code makes any attempt to ensure that kind of behavior, though I'm not sure I know what you mean. Because you're using checkboxes and not radio buttons, it's possible for more than one to be checked at the same time.

Comment: I can't do it with radio buttons, as I should choose between more options. I will change the parameters to be more clear.
 ["Boiled eggs","Eggs"],
 ["BLT Sandwich","Bacon"],
 ["BLT Sandwich","Lettuce"],
 ["BLT Sandwich","Tomato"],
 ["BLT Sandwich","Bread"],
 ["American Breakfast","Eggs"],
 ["American Breakfast","Bacon"],
 ["American Breakfast","Bread"],
 ["French Fries","Potatoes"]

Comment: If check only "Eggs" i will have product only for a "Boiled Eggs", not for "American Breakfast", because in "American Breakfast" I have "Bacon" and "Bread", too. Second example if i check "eggs" and "bacon"  the result will be the same (Boiled Eggs), because I don't have a Bread (unchecked). I hope you will understand me in this way.